# How can zsh and normal shell share environment variables and aliases without copying each other

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

Right now I tried to use zsh from normal Ubuntu bash. When I changed to zsh shell, I found previously environment variables (e.g. JAVA_HOME) in `.bashrc` can not migrate to `.zshrc` automatically. Now I just copy them (export, alias in .bashrc) to `.zshrc`. I want to know is there other convenient way to share these thing in `.bashrc` and do not need copy them explicitly? And even when I add something in `.zshrc` and then change to normal bash still could share them in `.zshrc` without copy them to `.bashrc`.

I tried to `source .zshrc` in `.bashrc`, then change to bash, found below error

```
exec bash
autoload: command not found
bash: /home/zhuguowei/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/zhuguowei/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 31: `for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do'
```

And in `.zshrc` I also tried `source .bashrc`, have error too

```
source .zshrc 
/home/zhuguowei/.bashrc:16: command not found: shopt
/home/zhuguowei/.bashrc:24: command not found: shopt
/home/zhuguowei/.bashrc:108: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:35: parse error near `]]'
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\u@\h:\w$
```

Comment: One option ought to be to source the .zshrc file from within the .bashrc file.

Comment: Hell no, sourcing rc of an incompatible shell is one of the stupidest suggestions ever (and unfortunately I see it suggested a lot). Write a base POSIX sh-compatible env file, and source it from `~/.zshenv`, `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Leave everything else shell-specific. You may want to have a look at my setup: https://github.com/zmwangx/dotfiles/blob/master/env, along with bash and zsh runcoms in their own respective subdirectories. I'm not advertising my setup as the best there is, but at least there's no breakage, and I can kickstart any other POSIX shell with the same base env.

Comment: Thanks @4ae1e1  finally I decided to adopt this way ： http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764600/how-can-you-export-your-bashrc-to-zshrc

Answer (score 1):

In `.bashrc` you can use `export` to export a variable (usually in UPPER_CASE) to the environnement that will be sent to commands executed from your shell.

Example of a simple `.bashrc`

```
# Here is the content of the .bashrc

export SOMETHING=42
```

Now in bash, after sourcing the bashrc, I have an environnement variable called `SOMETHING` that contains `42`

You can check what is the environnement beeing sent to process with the comand `env`

Now, in the opened `bash`, you can launch `zsh`, then check (with `env`) the zsh's current environnement.

Now in the opened `zsh`, you can just `echo $SOMETHING` and see the answer `42`

note: if you don't know why I used `42` : ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy))

Answer (score 0):

- I would (hard) link `.bashrc` & `.zshrc`

**OR**

- Source one of the two files from the other.

Comment: I tried your way , in `.bashrc` source `.zshrc`, then changed to bash, there are error. exec bash
autoload: command not found
bash: /home/zhuguowei/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: /home/zhuguowei/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh: line 31: `for config_file ($ZSH/lib/*.zsh); do'

Comment: This means your `.zshrc` contains both variable setting (like JAVA_HOME in your original post) and code. The latter could be specific to either bash or zsh. I'd suggest to separate variable setting and code. A file containing variable settings can be _sourced_ by both `.zshrc` and `.bashrc`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26020688/411282 which suggests putting shared parts in `.profile`