# zsh: command not found: pre-commit but package installed

Tags: python, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

Installed pre-commit successfully using the following command in VSCode:

```py
python3 -m pip install pre-commit --user
```

but when I try to do the pre-commit install, I get the error message:

```py
zsh: command not found: pre-commit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [commands not found on zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428374/commands-not-found-on-zsh)

Comment: the `PATH` entry for `--user` installs is usually `~/.local/bin` on linux -- also modern pip usually gives you a warning if it's installing to a place not on your PATH -- can you show the output of the `pip` command?

Comment: deleting the virtual env and recreating it fixed this for me

Comment: For me the issue was that I had installed python via asdf and I had to run the reshim command after installing pythong + pre-commit via the command: `asdf reshim python` see https://gist.github.com/rubencaro/888fb8e4f0811e79fa22b5ac39610c9e

Answer (score 8):

Try adding this command to your .zshrc so that it recognizes your .bashrc commands, something similar to yours was happening to me.

```
[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'
```

for more information: [How can you export your .bashrc to .zshrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764600/how-can-you-export-your-bashrc-to-zshrc)