# "Pre-commit" command is not found by bash but is installed on macOS

Tags: bash, git, git-commit, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

### Problem Description

I'm having trouble making commits, when I try to make a commit with the command, for example:

```
$ git commit -m "add readme"
pre-commit not found. Install pre-commit with the command pip3 install --user pre-commit or follow the steps on official documentation: https://pre-commit.com /#install
```

Following the steps described in the pre-commit installation documentation I installed by the command:

```
$ pip install pre-commit
```

However when I trigger the command the following error occurs:

```
$ pre-commit --version
bash: pre-commit: command not found
```

My attempt fails, so I've tried some other solutions for this but they didn't work.

#### Export bash:

I already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26020688/11111289) described that would be to export my `~./bashrc` with the command: `source ~/.profile` but the following error happens:

```
bash:/Users/pvieira/.profile: No such file or directory
```

#### Install using homebrew:

This results in the same error that occurs when manually installing by `pip` above.

Comment: pre-commit would not produce that output so it's something custom that you or your company has set up

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? Maybe pre-commit was installed only inside of a virtual env, but you are doing git commit outside of a virtualenv.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by simply restarting the terminal.

Comment: The solution that everyone forgets to do is finally here!

Answer (score 1):

> command not found

This error generally means that your shell could not find the an matching executable file in their hash or that the file is not longer located at the previous location. The shell creates a hash of all programs in the `PATH` environment variable when it loads.

Depending on your shell you can refresh their hash by running `hash` or `rehash`.

The reason reloading your shell or terminal fixes the issue is because it, in effect, creates a new hash. Along the same lines, restarting the computer also happens to recreate a new hash.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. In my case, I was using a virtual venv and the PATH was not pointing to the right location after venv activation. I suspect that this problem was related to the fact that I move the venv in the past. I recreated the venv to solve the problem and it updated the PATH properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have used MacOS. I solved this problem installed pre-commit by `brew install pre-commit`

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was that I used pip install instead of pip3 install which wasn't using the default python version. After adding this to the bash profile and restarting bash it started working

```
alias python='python3'
alias pip='pip3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu suggests installing `pre-commit` as `apt` package:

```
sudo apt install pre-commit
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by restarting my ubuntu system